# Creating a Javascript bar chart with two y-axis variables, one bottom up and one top down

Tags: javascript, graphing, bar-chart

I am looking for a bar chart component that supports graphing two variables on the y axis: one shown in a traditional "bottom up" style, the other shown from "top down"...

[image: Valid XHTML]

Just imagine a graph that shows votes over time for the US states.  Time is mapped on the X axis, i.e. variable one.  One set of bars (i.e. variable two) grow from the bottom up, showing how many votes have been cast at that point in time.  The other set of bars (i.e. variable three) grow from the top down and shows how much of the college-educated population hasn't voted yet.  So, over time, as you eye moves from left to right, you see the bars growing from the bottom up getting bigger, and the bars that grow from the top down getting smaller.

Its almost like a stacked bar chart, except instead of stacking two vars, I want one var to be stalactites and the other to be stalagmites.

I looked through a variety of JS libraries and haven't found one that contains such a component out of the box.

1. Are there any JS graphing libraries that support this style of bar chart?
2. If not, which JS graphing libraries have you found that are easily customizable to support such a chart?

Thanks!

Comment: I can put the image for you if you comment or edit the link into your question.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation of your desired output. If you post a link to your image from, say, imgur.com, we can edit it for you. I don't know if it has what you want, but have you looked at [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)?

Comment: In Excel that's a "100% stacked chart".

Answer (score 1):

take a look at highcharts.    it is a js plugin that does multiple x and y axis bar charts.

Answer (score 0):

Check this library: http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Basically, it allows you to draw any graph style with JS.